# Проверить переменную является она строкой без пробелов

Tags: zend-framework-2, php, переменные

Нужно проверить переменную является она строкой без пробелов. 
Читал вот это http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#alpha
там написано что нужно использовать класс Zend\Validator\Alpha, как оказывается его нету по приведенному пути. нашел класс `Zend\I18n\Validator\Alpha`

```
valid = new \Zend\I18n\Validator\Alpha();
valid->isValid('ok');
```

Приводит к исключению 
Zend\I18n\Filter component requires the intl PHP extension

Comment: короткий путь: sudo aptitude install php5-intl
длинный путь: ознакомиться с PCRE
хак, который не словит табы и прочую муть: if (strpos($str, ' ') !== false) { /*valid*/ } else { /*invalid*/ }

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Открой файл php.ini и раскомментируй строчку **extension=php_intl.dll**
2. Перезапусти веб-сервер.

Comment: Воспользуюсь, когда буду заливать на хостинг.